# Using promises in javascript to allow for unchained updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, promise

I am new to the javascript promise world and i wrote a code that updates my database table based on some params. but i want all these changes to be made at the same time, and i did some research and came across promise.all promise api. and i wanted to know what i was doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?
your help will be most appreciated.

promise code:

```
try {
  syncEntities = async () => {
    let saveTakerOrder;
    let tradePromises;

    // if no makers in the trade or the taker was not completely filled put it in the orders table
    saveTakerOrder = await dynamodb
      .put({
        TableName: process.env.ORDERS_TABLE_NAME,
        Item:
          makers.length === 0 ||
          taker.initial_quantity !== taker.quantity_removed
            ? taker
            : {
                ...taker,
                status: "CLOSED",
                orderRate: `${taker.side}#CLOSED#${taker.rate}`,
              },
      })
      .promise();

    // if makers exist
    if (makers.length > 0) {
      tradePromises = makers.map(async (maker) => {
        let savedTrade;
        let updatedOrder;
        // trade entity model
        const matchedTrade = {
          id: `TRD${uuid()}`,
          buy_order: taker.side === "BUY" ? taker.id : maker.id,
          sell_order: taker.side === "SELL" ? taker.id : maker.id,
          ticker: maker.ticker,
          rate: maker.rate,
          quantity: maker.quantity_removed,
          createdAt: date.toISOString(),
        };

        // Save the trade to the trades table
        savedTrade = await dynamodb
          .put({
            TableName: process.env.TRADES_TABLE_NAME,
            Item: matchedTrade,
          })
          .promise();

        // Update the order in the orders table if quantity is not filled ELSE close it if completely filled
        if (maker.quantity_removed !== maker.initial_quantity) {
          updatedOrder = await dynamodb
            .update({
              TableName: process.env.ORDERS_TABLE_NAME,
              key: { id: maker.id },
              UpdateExpression:
                "set quantity_removed = :quantity_removed, quantity_remaining = :quantity_remaining",
              ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":quantity_remaining": maker.quantity_remaining,
                ":quantity_removed": maker.quantity_removed,
              },
            })
            .promise();
        } else {
          updatedOrder = await dynamodb
            .update({
              TableName: process.env.ORDERS_TABLE_NAME,
              Key: { id: maker.id },
              UpdateExpression: "set #status = :status, orderRate = :orderRate",
              ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":status": "CLOSED",
                orderRate: `${maker.side}#CLOSED#${maker.rate}`,
              },
              ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#status": "status",
              },
            })
            .promise();
        }

        return Promise.all([savedTrade, updatedOrder]);
      });
    }

    return Promise.all([tradePromises, saveTakerOrder]);
  };

  await Promise.all([syncEntities]);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
}
```

Please can someone point out what i am doing wrong with this code or help me correct it Thanks?

Comment: remove the `await`s from `await dynamodb....`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the `await`s from the calls to the things you want to include in your `Promise.all`. The moment you `await` something it is going to resolve the promise before continuing. If you were to look at the object you get back from `await dynamodb.update(...).promise()`, for example, you'll notice that you have a `DynamoDBUpdateResponse` object (at least I think that's the type). But if you remove the `await` you'd have a `Promise<DynamoDBUpdateResponse>` object.

You can still get at the results of the promises after you call `await Promise.all`. Each item in the array will have a record in the resulting array.